# QGIS: ORS Tools giving consistent error when trying to change "Traveling Salesman [optional]" to anything except blank

Tags: error, travelling-salesman

I am having trouble with the ORS Tools plugin. In regards to the errors themselves, they are as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/Users/User/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/John/python/plugins/ORStools/common/client.py", line 157, in request
response, content = self.nam.request(self.url,
File "/Users/karlispanis/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/John/python/plugins/ORStools/common/networkaccessmanager.py", line 263, in request
raise self.http_call_result.exception
ORStools.common.networkaccessmanager.RequestsException: Network error #400: Error transferring https://api.openrouteservice.org/optimization? - server replied: Bad Request

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/User/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/John/python/plugins/ORStools/common/client.py", line 167, in request
self._check_status()
File "/Users/User/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/John/python/plugins/ORStools/common/client.py", line 223, in _check_status
raise exceptions.ApiError(
ORStools.utils.exceptions.ApiError: 400 ({"code":2,"error":"Duplicate job id: 1."}
)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/User/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/John/python/plugins/ORStools/proc/directions_points_layer_proc.py", line 163, in processAlgorithm
response = ors_client.request('/optimization', {}, post_json=params)
File "/Users/User/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/John/python/plugins/ORStools/common/client.py", line 179, in request
logger.log(f"Feature ID {post_json['id']} caused a {e.__class__.__name__}: {str(e)}", 2)
KeyError: 'id'

Execution failed after 0.31 seconds
```

Some things of note:

- The application only works on my point layer when it is set to "Point (Point)" and not when it is multipoint
- There are no issues otherwise when trying to route without the use of the Salesman option.
- When I try to change my point layer to multipoint it gives me this error when I try to run anything "Feature ID None caused a ApiError: 400 ({ error :{ code :2003, message : Parameter coordinates has incorrect value or format. }, info :{ engine :{ build_date : 2023-12-10T05:30:50Z , version : 7.1.0 }, timestamp :1702986538288}})"
- My point layer is also composed of points that were copied from another layer of points created by the "Line intersection" function

As far as the problem I am trying to solve is concerned, I want to try running traveling salesman but with a start point and end point being two separate things without returning to the same start point. Perhaps, pgRouting has my solution but I do not know how to operate it.